# Node JS readdir callback never called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read all files from a directory using fs.readdir. Here is the simplified code:

```
var updateFeaturesFromDir = async function(dir, recurse, logString, addedString, callback){
    console.log("hello"); //This is printed
    fs.readdir('.', (err, files) => {
        console.log(files); // This is never reached
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
    });

};
```

However, when running this, I only get the 'hello' printed to the console. Also, breakpoints set with vs code in the callback never trigger. I do not know why this is happening, since the code in the very same place worked yesterday and I do not know what change broke it.

I also tried it with an absolute path (`__dirname`) and it did not work.

I feel like I am missing something really obvious here but I cannot see it. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
node version: v14.16.0

here is how I get fs:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

EDIT 2:

After fixing this issue like in the accepted answer, I also had the same issue with other callback functions. I found out what the reason was: I for some dumb reason had a blocking function in the index.js file. After removing that, everything worked fine again. I thought I would add this in case someone faced similar issues.

Comment: Why do you have a callback in a async function? You should use either callbacks or promises, not both

Comment: Works fine in Node v14.15.1. What's your Node version? _(type `node -v`)_ and how do you require `fs`? Also, _"Here is the simplified code"_. Do you actually reproduce the problem when running this simplified code? If not, please delete your question and come back with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @mousetail I am new to node, how should I have done it?

Comment: Works fine with node 14.x.x, are you sure that you are invoking this function `updateFeaturesFromDir`?

Comment: You never use any `await` statements so you can simply remove the `async` from that function

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the async

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim yes, the hello statement is printed to the console.

Comment: @JakobTinhofer Can you get the files using this `var updateFeaturesFromDir = async function () {
  console.log("hello"); //This is printed
  var files = fs.readdirSync('.', []);
  console.log(files)
};`

Please do let me know.

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim yes, readdirSync did the trick. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following ways

Example 1:

```
import { readdirSync } from "fs";

const updateFeaturesFromDir = async function (
  dir,
  recurse,
  logString,
  addedString,
  callback
) {
  try {
    console.log("hello");
    const filses = readdirSync('your path here');
    console.log('filses: ', filses);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

Example 2:

```
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';

const updateFeaturesFromDir = async function (
  dir,
  recurse,
  logString,
  addedString,
  callback
) {
  try {
    console.log("hello");
    const filses = await readdir('your path here');
    console.log('filses: ', filses);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the first line tho, it threw an exception. I just imported fs like I wrote above, then used fs.readdirSync